# Problems printing with ruby to Brother TD-4000 label printer under Linux

Tags: ruby, linux, printing

I'd like to be able print out to a Brother TD-4000 label printer under Linux. The ultimate goal is to capture the output and send it to a remote printer via [Printnode](http://www.printnode.com) but for now, local is fine.

I found the gem [Escper](https://github.com/michaelfranzl/ruby-escper) which might help, but even with the most basic example, the printer remains stubbornly mute.

```
vp1 = Escper::VendorPrinter.new id: 1, name: 'Printer 1 USB', path: '/dev/usb/lp0', copies: 1
print_engine = Escper::Printer.new 'local', vp1
print_engine.open
print_engine.print 1, 'print text to printer 1'

# outputs
[ESCPER] [print] Printing on Printer 1 USB @ #<File:/dev/usb/lp0>.
[ESCPER] [print] Written text: print text to printer 1
 => [23, "print text to printer 1"] 

# but nothing comes out of the printer
```

The printer is on that port and I've made sure it's world writeable.

Does anyone have any experience with this printer (or another similar Brother one) with either this gem or using a different method?

Comment: To test the printer, use basic shell commands first. Consult the user manual for valid print commands, and put them into a file `test.bin`. Then try `cat test.bin > /path/to/printer`.